Why does this GCC code define a macro called 'void'?
I was reading the GCC implementation of malloc when I noticed this macro definition :
/*
  void* is the pointer type that malloc should say it returns
*/

#ifndef void
#define void      void
#endif /*void*/

Why does this macro exist ? What is to be gained by defining void as void ?

defined(void) returns 1
